# Why use double quotes in a [[ ]] test?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, variable, test

Let's say we have 2 integers in a bash script:

```
value1=5
value2=3
```

Then why do we need to use double quotes in case of a test ? For example:

```
if [[ "$value1" -eq "$value2" ]]
```

Why not just use the following ?

```
if [[ $value1 -eq $value2 ]]
```

To me, the double quotes don't make any sense.

Comment: Quoting in the shell has little to do with strings (as in data types.) It's really about preventing the shell from performing word splitting (and other kinds of expansions.)

Comment: While, as terdon pointed out, it is not *necessary* too quote variables in this specific construct (and, of course, with one-word-values anywhere), I'd like to give the advice to **always quote your vars.** Do you really know in wich contexts you can leave variables unquoted? The reason to quote at all, even if it's not necessary with `5` and `3`, is maintainability. The values may change later, and the resulting errors may not be obvious.

Comment: @sudodus I don't think that's true for `[[ ]]`, only for `[ ]`.

Comment: You are right, @BenjaminW. Word splitting is not the only case why it is a good idea to use double quotes for variables. There is also the case when a variable is blank. That will make the statement in [ ] fail (for example [ 2 -eq ] with an error, but [[ ]] is not vulnerable (like the case with word splitting).

Comment: _"Let's say we have 2 integers in a bash script:"_ - You don't have two integers, you have two strings containing a decimal integer representation. The only datatype shells know is strings; there are no integer variables in shell like there are in, say, C or Python.

Comment: If you knew for certain they would always have those values, the quotes wouldn't be necessary, but if you knew for certain they would always have those values there would be no point in comparing them for equality since three will never be equal to five.

Comment: @marcelm, Bash, ksh and Zsh have integer variables, and within `[[ ]]` they also coerce the operands of `-eq` to integers.

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how can I upvote and accept an answer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Word splitting.

This example is very improbable, *but possible*, so if you want to code defensively, cover your tracks with quotes:

```
$ set -x
$ value1=5
+ value1=5
$ value2=3
+ value2=3
$ [ $value1 -eq $value2 ]
+ '[' 5 -eq 3 ']'
```

OK, all good so far. Let's throw the wrench into the gears:

```
$ IFS=456
+ IFS=456
$ [ $value1 -eq $value2 ]
+ '[' '' -eq 3 ']'
bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

Oops.

```
$ [ "$value1" -eq "$value2" ]
+ '[' 5 -eq 3 ']'
```

Ahh.

Comment: But OP uses double brackets, so no word splitting takes place.

Comment: Yes, this isn't really relevant to bash's `[[   ]]` construct.

Comment: Eh? `[ $value1 -eq $value2 ]` with an empty `value1` would be `'[' -eq 3 ']'` with no `''` on the left-hand side.

Comment: I was surprised too, but there's the evidence.

Comment: This answer does not *directly* relate to the question. I'm surprised it was accepted. Setting as community wiki.

Answer (score 38):

You don't actually need the quotes here. This is one of the very few cases where it is safe to use a variable unquoted. You can confirm this with `set -x`:

```
$ var1=""
$ var2="3"
$ set -x
$ if [[ $var1 -eq $var2 ]]; then echo "match!"; else echo "no match!"; fi
+ [[ '' -eq 3 ]]
+ echo 'no match!'
no match!
$ if [[ "$var1" -eq "$var2" ]]; then echo "match!"; else echo "no match!"; fi
+ [[ '' -eq 3 ]]
+ echo 'no match!'
no match!
```

As you can see above, the quoted and unquoted versions of the test are resolved to the exact same thing by bash. The same should be true for `zsh` and, I think, any other shell that supports the `[[ ]]` operator.

Note that this is *not* the case with the more portable `[ ]`:

```
$ if [ $var1 -eq $var2 ]; then echo "match!"; else echo "no match!"; fi
+ '[' -eq 3 ']'
sh: [: -eq: unary operator expected
+ echo 'no match!'
no match!
```

The `[ ]` construct, unlike the `[[ ]]` one, does require quoting.

---

Some useful links to learn more about when and why quoting is required:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/)

Comment: In this case with integer variables it would be better to declare them as such. `declare -i var1=` is `0` when evaluated.

Comment: Note that `-eq` is _arithmetic_ comparison, so you can even leave the `$` out (in `[[ .. ]]`), and write `[[ a -eq b ]]`. With string comparison, you need the `$`, of course, so `[[ $a = $b ]]`

Comment: The right hard should still be quoted if the variable has any glob characters, e.g. `a='*'; [[ 'a' = $a ]] && echo oops`

Comment: @user000001 good point. Although, of course, it's very possible that you _want_ those expanded. For example, I would expect this to be a match: `var1="afoob"; var2="a*b"; [[ $var1 = $var2 ]] && echo match`. If you want to use the glob characters without their acting as a glob in a globbing context (such as the `[[ ]]`) then you need to quote, yes.

Comment: @ilkkachu, that surprises me. I thought that "bare" variables would only be considered within an array subscript or `((...))` or `$((...)`. It appears to work, but (old grumpy man, enable) I don't like it.

Comment: @glennjackman, well, sorry to be the one to tell you that, but yeah, the operands to `-eq` and friends inside `[[ ]]` are arithmetic contexts, too. :) (Related: [Automatic variable expansion inside bash \[\[ \]\] command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/485766/170373))

Comment: Related: [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) "Word splitting and filename expansion are not performed on the words between the [[ and ]]; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, command substitution, process substitution, and quote removal are performed."

Comment: For the record, the only **universally portable** safe places to **not** quote variables (and other expansions) are the **first** field of the `case` statement (but **not** the *patterns to match* in the case statement), and in **regular** variable assignments (but **not** in variable assignments as part of `export`).

Answer (score 16):

Even though the double quotes aren't necessary, reasons to use them are:

- Good practice/habit: In *this* case they aren't necessary, but in general double quotes *are* to avoid unintended word splitting.
- Because `value1` and `value2` are variable, and you might not know what they contain.  Otherwise you might as well ask, "Why bother with variables instead of checking `if [[ 5 -eq 3 ]]`?  Or taking it further, why bother with the `if` at all when you already know that 5 isn't equal to 3?  It's often better to be defensive. (It's true that word-splitting won't happen in `[[`, but cases where word-splitting does *not* happen are rare.  Again, see the first point.)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to your question, but I use

> if (( $value1 ==  $value2 )); then

when I compare numbers but there you also don't have to use quotes.

Comment: `if (( value1 == value2 )); then`.  In arithmetic contexts, you don't even need the `$`.  This question, however, seems to focus on variables used within `[[ ... ]]` tests.

Comment: I know. But I frankly don't use this feature because I want to have my variable names be consistent and thus use $ as a prefix all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right!

The quoting within double square brackets makes no sense at all, at least in this case.

But since I use double quotes daily -- especially for single square bracket expressions, passing arguments to functions and scripts, as well as variable assignment sometimes (which is completely useless for simple delcarations) -- **I guess some people, at least I do, write double quotes around variable expansions instinctively**.

> Double quoting can give you a sense of savety. It is like coming home
>   where double quotes are. - D. Kummer

A benefit of doing *double quotes consequently and comprehensibly* -- but only as it makes sense -- is that coworkers who are new to bash can learn **how to write more stable scripts**. 
It also accentuates the fact that *the art of data processing with bash* is more about **separating data streams (including variables) by field separators and pipe them through filters**. As soon as you got your data chunks separated from the stream, **hold them together with double quotes!**

Another benefit could be the better readability of bash scripts with double quoted strings **within a code highlighting editor**.